# Using NODE_PATH in vscode debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I want to auto-restart my nodeJs debugger, so I have to use Nodemon for that.

My **package.json** scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_PATH=src env-cmd -f ./src/config/env/development.env nodemon ./src/app.js",
    "test": "NODE_PATH=src env-cmd -f ./src/config/env/test.env jest"
}
```

and here's **launch.json** file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.js",
            "restart": true,
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon"
        }
    ]
}
```

now after running the debugger I got the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'config/cache'

I guess I should tell the `launch.json` configuration to use `NODE_PATH=src` as I did in the `package.json` file. I'm not sure if it's the case.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I created a small nodejs app, and copied your launch.json. The only difference I had is this `"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\.bin\\nodemon"`

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you've set NODE_PATH to your src folder. Try setting it to the directory that stores the node_modules folder.

Try any of the following:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH
NODE_PATH=./node_modules
```

Comment: But I want the base path to start from the `src` folder, if I made this change I should change all the `require` statements path in my project.